# How to extract links from "See Also" section of an article in Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there a way to extract all links from only the "See Also" section in a Wikipedia article through Wikpedia API?

I wondering a method but I'm not able to find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using Wikipedia API with [action=parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse). For this goal we need two properties: `sections` and `links`. For example for Wikipedia article [Chicago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago) we use the next query to get the **index** of the section with name "See also":

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=sections&page=Chicago
```

From response we see that it is **43**. Then we use that index to get the links only in this section:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=links&page=Chicago&section=43
```

**Note:** The last response can include also links which come from some templates, as in our case *Portal:Chicago* and *Portal:Illinois*. If you want you can filter them by using namespace **&ns=0** in your request.

Comment: Is there a way to get all the sections and links from a wiki api endpoint and figure what link belongs to what section in our application logic?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly though the API. MediaWiki tracks links on a per-page basis, it doesn't store information about which section the link comes from.

I think your best option is to get the HTML of the section, parse it and collect all `<a href` elements.